# A typescript question to implement runtime inheritance

Tags: javascript, typescript, oop, inheritance

I saw a question about typescript. The question is:

Implementing the constructor by JS and ensure that "magicMike" has the ability of "mike".

```js
declare interface Book {};

declare interface BookOfSpells extends Book {};

declare class Career {};

class Wizzard<c extends Career> {
  spellBooks: Array<BookOfSpells>;
  public castSpell() {}
  constructor(career: c) {

    // Complement code

  }
}

class Engineer extends Career {
  public buildBabel() {}
}

const mike = new Engineer();

// Complement code

const magicMike = new Wizzard(mike);

// Achieve:

magicMike.buildBabel();
```

I have some ideas but none of them feel like the best solution. How to solve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing that we have to multiple inheritance in typescript is [mixins](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/mixins.html), which are higher-order functions that take a class and return a modified class.  Instead of defining `Wizard` as a class, we can define it as a mixin that modifies any `Career` class.

```
const applyWizardry = <TBase extends Constructor<Career>>(Base: TBase) => {
    return class extends Base {
        spellBooks: Array<BookOfSpells> = [];
        public castSpell() {}

        constructor(...args: any[]) {
            // call parent constructor
            super(...args);

            // wizard constructor stuff
        }
    }
}
```

We can create `magicMike` in two steps:

```
const MagicEngineer = applyWizardry(Engineer);
const magicMike = new MagicEngineer();
```

or in one:

```
const magicMike = new (applyWizardry(Engineer))();
```

Now Mike is able to directly call methods from both the `applyWizardry` mixin and the `Engineer` class:

```
magicMike.buildBabel();
magicMike.castSpell();
```

[Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/vWk4Pw)